# How to convert from Oracle Syntax to Spotfire

Tags: oracle, syntax, calculated-columns, spotfire, tibco

How can I convert these 3 columns in oracle syntax into Spotfire to create calculated columns?

```
decode(nvl(sum(a.out_qty),0),0,0,round(60/(decode(sum(a.std_out),0,1,(sum(a.std_out)/nvl(sum(a.out_qty),1)))),2)) as st_upeh,

decode(nvl(sum(a.lot_time),0),0,0,round(nvl(sum(a.out_qty),0)*60/sum(a.lot_time),2)) as lottime_upeh,

round(60/decode(sum(A.std_out),0,1,sum(A.std_out)/nvl(sum(A.out_qty),1))*(sum(A.std_time)/nvl(sum(A.work_time),1)) ,2) AS real_upeh
```

Comment: You could improve readability of your question by formatting the code you posted, e.g. _"create code fences with backticks ` or tildes ~"_. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Can you add to your question your current efforts? Thanks!